# How can I write a PL/SQL procedure to copy tables and contents from another account

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, procedure

I need to write a PL/SQL procedure to create tables that match the ones in another account(I have access to that account). They need to have same columns and types. Also, they need to be filled with the same data

Help me!

EDIT:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MakeTables
  2  AS
  3  BEGIN
  4  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  5  'CREATE TABLE Table1 AS (SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_ACCT.Table1);
  6  CREATE TABLE Table2 AS (SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_ACCT.Table2);
  7  CREATE TABLE Table3 AS (SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_ACCT.Table3);
  8  CREATE TABLE Table4 AS (SELECT * FROM ANOTHER_ACCT.Table4)';
  9  END;
 10  /

Procedure created.
```

But when I run this I get this error:

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2  MakeTables;
  3  END;
  4  /
BEGIN
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at "BS135.MAKETABLES", line 4
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You've done a fair job of describing your requirements. You haven't provided any of the effort you've made to figure this out yourself, though, or any information about your database schema. Please [edit] your question and include the SQL you've tried so far that isn't working the way you expect, and explain what's not working. Then you can ask a specific question that we can answer based on that information. Thanks.

Comment: Dude, you morphed your original question into another question!  Execute Immediate executes a single SQL statement.  I don't think you can do what you are attempting.  Maybe encase in a BEGIN/END block?  Not sure, but try it, or call each create separately.

Comment: I know at the same time I am trying to work on it and I make progress.

Comment: just put each statement in a separate `execute immediate`. i would not recommend using this plsql function to move data around. oracle provides much better ways of doing that (imp/exp, rman, transportable tablespace etc'). try defining your specific needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say, another "account", do you mean, another "user/schema"?  If so, this can be simple.  Go read/google about "oracle create table as select".  This lets you create a table from a select statement, so you could issue a statement such as

```
create table new_table as select * from other_schema.old_table
```

You don't need any PL/SQL unless you wanted to automate the process for creating many tables.  Then you could query the data dictionaries as a driver.

(also, please read on how to ask proper questions here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask )